# Why do diodes adjust to reverse breakdown voltage when we apply a voltage more than the breakdown voltage?

Tags: diodes, reverse-breakdown

When a voltage(neglecting sign as I am considering reverse bias region) more than the reverse breakdown is applied then why diodes adjust themselves to reverse breakdown voltage? Please provide an intuitive answer. What is happening physically?
What happens to the remaining voltage applied?

Comment: When you apply a voltage, irrespective of the diode's reverse voltage being exceeded, the same voltage occurs across the diode terminals even if 1,000,000 amps is caused to flow through the diode.

Comment: Do you understand what a depletion region is and how it gets wider under reverse bias?

Comment: @Andyaka I think the OP is asking about the actual physics behind the zener IV curve, not a constant voltage model.

Comment: Yes I understand that but I don't understand why it adjusts to reverse bias voltage only even when we apply higher voltage

Comment: If 1000000 amps flows through the diode, I don't think there would be a diode, only smoke.

Comment: It takes more energy for electrons to cross (or rather, mess up) the wider depletion region during avalanche breakdown which means more voltage drop, but this voltage change is very small with respect to the change in current which is why a zener explodes if you directly apply even a moderately higher voltage than breakdown directly to it. It requires too much current to increase voltage drop to eat up the extra voltage so you use a resistor to offload the extra voltage elsewhere. This is what lets you approximate the voltage drop in breakdown as constant.

Comment: is this in a simulator, or on the bench in real life? Because in real life, they generally don't 'adjust themselves to reverse breakdown voltage', they generally break down (the clue is in the name of the voltage!) If they fail open, they'll adjust themselves to the applied voltage. If they fail short, they'll adjust the applied voltage to zero, by drawing whatever current is needed to do that. If that's a big current, then only for a while, until they melt. I can imagine some simulators would 'adjust the voltage to the breakdown voltage'.

Comment: You cannot put 5V across a 4.5V diode and get 4.5V across the diode - without some series element between the voltage and the diode.  If you put 5V across a 4.5V diode directly you will get 5V across the diode, not 4.5V.

Comment: I have a problem with the term *"the diode adjusts to.."* as if the diode somehow changes itself. Just like a dam of water does not "adjust itself" to the height of  the water when it rises and spills over it.

Comment: The amswer if probably some riff on Ohm's law, depending on what you actually mean.

Comment: The extra energy becomes heat.